# msi silent installation. There is still dialog UI appears after the installation

Tags: dialog, windows-installer

I use silent installation for msi product using command line. When the installation finishes, there is an information wizard dialog appearing. My problem is why does that dialog appear even though I used silent installation command. The silent installation in my case handles only the next button prompts. Is there someway to also handle the last information dialog that appears after installation. the command I used for this is (msiexec /i Product.msi /qn )

Answer (score 2):

If you ran the msi with `/qn` and still saw a dialog appear then the UI isn't coming from MSI it's coming from a custom action.  It is a violation of best practices to author UI to appear in a silent installation but odds are the person who wrote the MSI doesn't know that and didn't test the silent install.

The only thing you can do is examine the MSI using ORCA and create a transform to eliminate the custom action.  I can't tell you exactly how to do that because I would need to look at the exact MSI to know what needs to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment christopher. I think I might need a custom action to handle that dialog. I thinks ORCA is an external tool that helps handling it. I don't no if it might help since I am looking for a way to automate the whole criteria.